# Heroku move region

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have been trying to migrate my app to a new region for a while now. It is on the hobby plan and I don't want to create a new one with the same region and manually move everything.

Following the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration), I reached the step:
`heroku fork --from fapp --to sapp --region eu`

**Getting:**

```
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
 !    No slug for app fapp was found.
 !    Push some code to fapp before forking it.
```

I can read that it says that code is not pushed to the app. But I don't know what it means by that. The app is already in prod, it's functional, it's connected to github and even has automatic deploys activated.

**Some sanity checks:**

```
git --version
git version 2.30.2.windows.1

heroku version
heroku/7.59.2 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0

git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fapp.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:edited/fapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:edited/fapp.git (push)
```

- I am logged in `heroku login`
- I am logged in `heroku container:login`
  (doubt it's needed)
- Don't know if it matters: I used to run `git push heroku master`, but now I'm running `git push origin main` for my automatic deploys via Heroku

**EDIT**: Running `heroku apps:info -a fapp` gives

```
=== fapp
Auto Cert Mgmt: true
Dynos:          web: 1
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/fapp.git
Owner:          redacted@email.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      0 B
Slug Size:      0 B
Stack:          container
Web URL:        https://fapp.herokuapp.com/
```

Please keep in mind the app is not actually called `fapp`, but I did not want to self-advertise.

Comment: "is `heroku-fork` now deprecated?"—that looks pretty clear from the output, doesn't it?

Comment: What am I supposed to use then?

Comment: Can't you just redeploy your code to a new app and then reconfigure your DNS?

Comment: I'm already on the Hobby plan, so nope

Comment: I can't redeploy my code to a new app since I am on the hobby plan on the current app. I don't want to pay again for the Hobby plan.

Comment: "I used to run `git push heroku master`, but now I'm running `git push origin main` for my automatic deploys via Heroku"—you also say you have GitHub connected. Do I understand that your `origin` is GitHub, so you're pushing there, and then your app is being deployed to Heroku via the GitHub integration?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: GitHub deploys bypass the underlying Git repository that would be used if you `git push`ed directly to Heroku. I suspect that might be part of the problem. Trying to find a reference.

Comment: Try `heroku apps:info -a fapp` to see the app confiuration

Comment: I updated my question to show this info @BeppeC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heroku-fork` still works. But it only works if there is actually any code to fork. The important lines here are:

```
 !    No slug for app sourceapp was found.
 !    Push some code to sourceapp before forking it.
```

Also important: `heroku-fork` will not work with container apps.

Note: you may be able to make `heroku-fork` work with a container app if it was originally built with a standard buildpack and converted into a container app (as reported in the comments below), but standard container apps will not work.

Comment: I edited the question, I now need an answer to help me solve the issue, not just understand it. Thank you!

Comment: You mention in your edit: 

`I am logged in heroku container:login (doubt it's needed)`



 Is this app a container app?  `heroku fork` will not work with a container app.

Comment: Yes, this is a container app. I see, so we can't fork container apps, alright. Please update your answer stating container apps don't support heroku fork so I can mark it as answered. Cheers

Comment: I was able to do it with a container app, but I suspect this app was a standard Java buildpack then converted to container. You could try to set the buildback with the Heroku CLI then fork it. If it works you can then build/push an image (which will make it again a containerized app)

Answer (score 0):

From your application info:

```
Repo Size:      0 B
Slug Size:      0 B
```

Nothing else seems wrong here without the repo, please re-check your repository. Sometimes I create an empty file and push to GitHub just to check if the file also get's deployed in Heroku, you may try this.

Comment: This is not it, I regularly deploy my stuff and it updates correcty everywhere