# Heroku Push some code to repo before forking it

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku

I have been trying to migrate my app to a new region for a while now. It is on the hobby plan and I don't want to create a new one with the same region and manually move everything.

Following the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration), I reached the step:
`heroku fork --from fapp --to sapp --region eu`

**Getting:**

```
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
HEROKU FORK IS UNMAINTAINED AND MAY NO LONGER FUNCTION.
 !    No slug for app fapp was found.
 !    Push some code to fapp before forking it.
```

I can read that it says that code is not pushed to the app. But I don't know what it means by that. The app is already in prod, it's functional, it's connected to github and even has automatic deploys activated.

**Some sanity checks:**

```
git --version
git version 2.30.2.windows.1

heroku version
heroku/7.59.2 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0

git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/fapp.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:edited/fapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:edited/fapp.git (push)
```

- I am logged in `heroku login`
- I am logged in `heroku container:login`
  (doubt it's needed)
- Don't know if it matters: I used to run `git push heroku master`, but now I'm running `git push origin main` for my automatic deploys via Heroku

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70281616/354577). You've just added a bit more information (and largely ignored comments on the old question asking for more information). You should have [edited that one instead of reposting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/248627), which would have "bumped" it and attracted more attention. Instead, you appear to have accepted an answer that may not be correct. Please do _not_ repost questions.

Comment: I suggest you _unaccept_ the answer on your previous question, add a comment on that answer, and edit your question to include the new information you show here.

Comment: Understandable. I accepted that answer because it was techincally correct and it answered my question, which was indeed unclear. I made the suggested edits now @Chris

Comment: Great, thank you! It's a lot easier to maintain a list of questions and answers when we don't have duplicates :-). I'll try to help via your original question.